# iPhone Memory Management

Tags: ios4

I have a method as follows. I want to know if the returned dictionary is autoreleased or not.

```
- (NSDictionary *)someMethod {
    NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];           //did not autorelease it here

    //-------------------------------
    //Some code
    //-------------------------------
    return (NSDictionary *) myDict;
}
```

Note: I haven't added autorelease while initializing the object on purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myDict would **not** be autoreleased. Would be retained. Replace the return line for

> return [myDict autorelease]; // no cast needed

Otherwise you are most likely introducing a leak.

Comment: Will returning NSMutableDictionary automatically typecast it to a NSDictionary? Please see the return type of the method.

Comment: NSMutableDictioanry is a subclass of NSDictionary thus no cast needed. An NSMutableDictioanry is a NSDictionary (not the other way thoug).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you must do autorelease not release

```
return [myDict autorelease];
```